# How to add item in nav menu in wordpress dashboard?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wp-nav-menu-item

How can I add a button or link to nav menu item for area that I refer to it in image attached below in wordpress dashboard?

What hook or function can I use?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use custom link option, add your link there and give some id to that menu, style it like a button using additional css. You can also use mega menu plugin for advance menu styling and creation.